# How portable is JavaFX 2?

Tags: javafx-2, portability

I am thinking of kicking off a **JavaFX** project on my **64-bit Windows 7 machine**. What I am doing is designing a full-screen console application. It's not interactive aside from a barcode scanner.

I'm designing this for what I think would be an Ubuntu laptop or some other Linux variation, although a different Windows OS is a possibility too (as well as 32 bit). From what I understand Java FX version 2.x has made great advancements in portability from its predecessor, but I wanted to ask the community here what their experience was in deploying JavaFX apps.

**Have you had success using them on a variety of different architectures? What are some problems you have encountered?**

Comment: The main problem of the desktop Java is that regular users (not developers) don't have Java installed on their machines, and they just don't know / don't want to know how to install. And that alone is enough to avoid Java on desktop, using Swing, AWT, SWT or JavaFX.

Comment: Just package the JRE with your application, it's going to bloat it but at least you have full control.  You're going to have the same problem with almost any desktop software.  I've had to install that vc++ redistributable so many times now...

Comment: Well, I have control over these systems, so I can still a JRE if needs be. My primary concern was OS compatibility and 32 bit vs 64 bit architecture... yada yada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout EstiMate for an example of an all-in-one jar which is runnable via double click.

https://bitbucket.org/atill/estimate/downloads

It requires Java7u10 installed.  I plan to make a proper installer for it later on, using the javafx maven plugin.  https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin.  I haven't tested it on Linux or Mac but it does work across winXP 32bit and 64bit windows7.

Comment: I've had a report that this does in fact work well under 64bit Linux.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu x64 but do remember that *nix has different directories than win. When I launched it, it hang on creating dirs?/db? and the second time I could not add new tasks..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I really appreciate it.  Did you try the SNAPSHOT release or 0.2?  I got similar feedback with the SNAPSHOT and fixed some concurrency bugs, although I couldn't reproduce that exact issue Myself. If it persists could you create a bug on the project issue tracker?  Hopefully there is some exceptions raised on the console.

Comment: I filed some bugs on the project issue tracker. I will try to help as much as I can. Cheers!

Comment: That feedback has narrowed down the Linux issues, I have commented on the bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your barcode scanner works the same on ubuntu as on win and you are not using any external libraries, you won't notice the difference between those systems from your app.

I found installing oracle JRE on ubuntu the most difficult task. (with JRE_HOME, etc.) Even on Archlinux was easier than ubuntu.

Nevertheless, once the JRE is set, your app will run even on Raspberry Pi (which is ARM not x86)

Remember about file system differences between systems.