# javaFX2 miglayout portability

Tags: javafx-2, portability, miglayout

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm just starting to venture into the UI world of it.
I've looked at what framework and tools to use.
My goals are:

1. Try to avoid implementing too much low level stuff through using an
   existing framework.
2. Use portable libraries (I heard that not all libraries are made equal)

As for everything I do, I start with a lot of documentation and research and right now my choice is landing on javaFX and miglayout.

I develop with Linux Ubuntu (currently 13.04) but my user base will be a mix of windows and Ubuntu and maybe some MAC users.

I wanted to know from people with way more experience, their pain points while developing with javaFX2 and migLayout when it comes to portability to other OS.

I have found this thread:
[How portable is JavaFX 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202987/how-portable-is-javafx-2)
But the answer I'm looking for is not: it works in "X" but rather. To make it work in "X" and "Y". "a", "b" and "c" will have to be taken care of. handling "z" is hard because etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is properly installed [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), And with a little help from your preferred `IDE` you will get almost a complete portable working environment ).

Using [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) will hide the complexity behind generating a runnable `jar` file, for serious project using a dependency manager will be  a must , both [Gradle](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle) and [Maven](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) have good `JavaFX` plugin for build automation (by using  Maven, you can clone  my `Github` repository and start working  immediately whatever the `OS` you're running),for more about `JavaFX` and `Java SE` integration see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18445211/1120221) from a `OpenJDK` contributor.

> javaFX2 miglayout portability

[Miglayout](https://java.net/projects/miglayoutfx2/pages/Home) has a `JavaFX` plugin all you need is to add `miglayout-javafx.jar` and the `miglayout-core.jar` to your `CLASSPATH`, so there is no portability issues with `MigLayout`.

`MigLayout` is a real powerful layout manager (especially when it comes to `Swing`),  but I prefer going the idiomatic way of building `JavaFX` user interfaces (essentially,  enterprise and data-driven applications) by using [fxml](/questions/tagged/fxml) and [scenebuilder](/questions/tagged/scenebuilder).

#### more resources :

- [GUI Architectures,by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)
- [JavaFX community website](https://www.java.net//community/javafx)
- [The FX Experience blog](http://fxexperience.com/)

Comment: Hi @tarrsalah, thanks a lot for this fantastic, complete, detailed answer. There aren't many architecture resources online in comparison of coding tutorial.

A quality application relies on a good architecture. It's unfortunate that too much time is spent on the coding and not much on how it will look like as a whole.

Your github repository uses the same username I suppose?

Thanks again. If I could vote +2 I would have.

Comment: You are welcome @ndefontenay , yes, I'm [@tarrsalah](https://github.com/tarrsalah) on github.